# How to delete a "tree" of data from sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table structure similar to:

```
Portfolios
  Properties
   Units
    Leases
```

All tables are setup with foreign key relationships and cascade deletes.  I want to be able to delete a portfolio, which would in turn delete all properties assigned to that portfolio, all units assigned to those properties, and all leases assigned to those units.

I'm getting errors similar to:

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_Leases_Units". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb", table "Leases", column 'UnitId'.
```

What is the proper way to delete a "tree" of data like this?

If it matters, I'm using MS SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Are you sure you've got CASCADE DELETE set? That's meant to work.

Comment: Can a unit be associated with more than one lease, or a least involve more than one unit?

Comment: @John Yes, there can be multiple leases per unit

Comment: in this case, you're deleting a Unit, which deletes the Leases for that Unit. Is it possible that one of the leases being deleted also involved a Unit which has not yet been deleted?

Comment: @John Not really.  Leases can only be assigned to one unit, so if the unit is being deleted, all of its leases should be deleted as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `FK_Leases_Units` is setup to cascade delete?  Every FK on the tree must be setup to cascade delete or none of it works...looks like the lowest level isn't set this way.

I'd double check this, if it's setup to cascade, you shouldn't be getting that error...it'd delete all rows with that UnitId instead of complaining the parent's missing.

Comment: The table design I have is a bit more complicated and does not fit a traditional tree.  Though, I designed the cascades such that everything should get deleted if the top level item is.  Maybe I just need to go back and verify the cascades.  There are definitely "map" tables in the design that may cause grief.

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure you delete the records in the right order.  you can't delete a record that is a key to another record in another table.  Check you deletion order and you'll find the problem.

Comment: No, that's the point of CASCADE DELETE; it means it should do all the looking-up for you instead of you having to delete the records one by one yourself.